# SF book where a boy loses an arm, moves from New York to Ireland

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

This book was written in the past 5 years I think.

A kid who lost an arm went selectively mute for the longest time. He lived in New York. He moved to Ireland and somewhere along the way someone gave him a computer that helped him talk by typing what he wanted to say. Then he found a portal to another world in his new house and he ended up transported to a dying world that gets colder and colder every year. I think the cover was of a storm.

That's all I remember, thanks to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 6):

*The Lighthouse Land*, of [The Lighthouse Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lighthouse_Trilogy), by [Adrian McKinty](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?37299).

> ### The Lighthouse Land
>
> The Lighthouse Land (Abrams, 2006) is the first installment of The
> Lighthouse Trilogy. It tells the story of Jamie O'Neill, a cancer
> survivor who has **lost his left arm** and since has **refused to speak**. The
> book sets its stage in Harlem, **New York**, where Jamie and his mother,
> Anna, live until they receive a letter informing them that Anna has
> inherited the Lighthouse House and Muck Island, both in Ireland, from
> her grandfather. **Upon moving to Ireland**, Jamie meets a new friend,
> Ramsay, and the two of them discover a secret about the lighthouse: a
> **secret room**. Inside this room is an object, referred to as the salmon,
> which **takes them to a new world** and a new adventure. There they come
> across strange new beings; aliens from a world completely unlike our
> own. The first of these aliens they meet is Wishaway, princess of the
> Aldans, whom Jamie later falls in love with. She is described as
> having four fingers on each hand, yellow hair, and pointed ears. Jamie
> learns her land is in danger from a coming foe, and the hopes of the
> Aldan people rest on his shoulders.

> The book was shortlisted for the
> 2008 Young Hoosier Award and also for the 2008 Beehive Award.

Comment: "There they come across strange new beings; aliens from a world completely unlike our own. The first of these aliens they meet is Wishaway, princess of the Aldans, whom Jamie later falls in love with. She is described as having four fingers on each hand, yellow hair, and pointed ears." Completely unlike our own, but somewhat like *The Simpsons*.